# problem with commit message after conflicts been resolved when merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I am new in Git. Currently, I am experiencing this scenario:

Step 0. I am working on a **sub**-branch

Step 1. I have added & commited file1, file2, file3 on my **sub**-branch with commit message **msg1, msg2, msg3** respectively.

Step 2. I `checkout master` to switch to **master** branch

Step 3. I `pull origin master` to update master branch with latest origin version code

Step 4. I `merge sub-branch` to merge my working code to the current master branch code

Then, I got conflict in **file2**,

Then, I manually resolved the conflicts. Now, **file2** needs to be added because there is changes on this file.

Step 5. I `add file2` in master branch, because I have resolved the conflicts on this file

Step 6. What commit message should I write now? the **msg2** only? or **msg1, msg2, msg3** all needs to be rewritten now? (I don't want to loose the commit messages **msg1,msg2,msg3** for the files I worked)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not writing a new commit message for those merged commits; you're writing a commit message for the merge commit itself. Your history is going to look like this:

```
- x - o - o - o (origin/master) - X (master)
   \                             /
    1 - 2 - 3 (sub-branch) ------
```

The commit message you're writing is for `X`. Commits `1`, `2`, and `3` are ancestors, still in the history, and they still have their commit messages. There's no way to change those with a merge.

The commit message for `X`, if you don't have conflicts, will default to something like `Merge branch 'sub-branch'`. If you do have conflicts, it'll still have that as the first line, but also a list of files which had conflicts:

```
 Merge branch 'sub-branch'

 Conflicts:
     file2
```

This is a gentle hint that you've done something more significant than just a simple merge - you had to do some manual work to resolve conflicts in `file2`. If you like, you can add a quick note about what caused those conflicts and how they were resolved. Otherwise, just use that message as-is! Remember, this is only a description of the merge (and conflict resolution). The commits you merged have their own commit messages.

Answer (score 3):

Once you resolve the conflict and `git add <conflicted file>` when you go on to `git commit` it should provide a prebuilt commit message for the merge and any resolved commits. Does it not? The other merged commits won't be lost, you shouldn't have to rewrite anything.

1. Commit to BranchB
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git pull origin master`
4. `git merge BranchB`
5. Resolve conflicts in file(s)
6. `git add <conflicted file(2)>`
7. `git commit`

Step 7: if called without params should open the default commit message editor with a decent message explaining the merge and resolved conflicts (I believe)